# C++ calculation evaluated to 0

Tags: c++, double

I'm parsing a file and trying to decode coordinates to the right unit.
What happens is that this code is evaluated to 0. If I type it into gdb the result is correct.

```
int pLat = (int)(
        (argv[6].data() == "plus" ? 1 : -1)
        * (     atoi(argv[7].data()) 
              + atoi(argv[8].data()) / 60. 
              + atoi(argv[9].data()) / 36000.)
        * 2.145767 * 0.0001);
```

I'm doing a (degrees, minutes, tenth seconds) conversion to wgs. Is there something wrong with this code?

Comment: Is `argv` a `vector<string>`?

Comment: Is the result always 0, or only for certain values of `argv`?

Comment: Without knowing the value of `argv` it's impossible to say what this should evaluate to.

Comment: `argv` is usually used to mean the command-line arguments given to a program, but it's obviously not in this case.  If you could show us the definition, and some sample values, we could help you better.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to convert degrees to WGS84 coordinates but multiplying instead of dividing, which will give a very small result that will round to zero (aside from being wrong).

Comment: Does `argv[9]` hold arcseconds or 1/10 of arcseconds? If the former, the `/ 36000.` should be `/ 3600.`

Comment: Edited the question, so it's a real question now

Comment: @Alexander Stolz: Without the declaration of `argv` it will never be a real question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to convert degrees to WGS84 coordinates, there are two errors:

- The conversion factor is out by a factor of 10 (180/2<sup>23</sup> is approximately 2.145767*10<sup>-5</sup>, and you have 2.145767*10<sup>-4</sup>)
- You are multiplying by the conversion factor when you should be dividing by it. This will give you a very small number, and the cast to `int` will give zero.

Comment: And it looks like the conversion from seconds to decimal degrees is also off by a factor of 10, 36000 instead of 3600.

Comment: 36000 is right, I get degrees, minutes and tenth seconds.
But the rest was wrong, works now thanks

Comment: Code that uses `atoi` cannot and will not work in general case. Any resemblance of "working" is temporary and purely accidental.

Answer (score 7):

You are casting it to int, which means you are only taking the integral part.

`(int)0.7 == 0`. If the expression you cast to an int is < 1, the result will be 0 due to the cast. Since `2.145767 * 0.0001` is a very small number, the chances of this happening are pretty high.

Consider using floats or doubles exclusively.

In general:

`(int)x.y == x` for all floats and doubles `x.y`. (ignoring possible overflow)

Answer (score 4):

Just plugging in random values for argv[6..9] seems to produce numbers smaller than 1. When cast to `int`, these values will be truncated to 0. If your conversion factors are correct, you may need to use a floating-point type to represent the result.

Answer (score 4):

I'll assume for now that you have defined

```
vector<string> argv;
```

and initialized it somehow.

`string::data` doesn't do what you seem to want. Actually, it does almost nothing. It just returns a const pointer to a version of the string, **which isn't guaranteed to be null-terminated.**

To compare a `string` to a character literal, just use `==`.

To pass a `string` to a C function, use `string::c_str`.

And, you are putting a fractional number into an `int`.

```
double pLat = ( // use a floating-point type
        (argv[6] == "plus" ? 1 : -1) // compare string using ==
        * (     atoi(argv[7].c_str()) // get C string using c_str
              + atoi(argv[8].c_str()) / 60. 
              + atoi(argv[9].c_str()) / 36000.)
        * 2.145767 * 0.0001);
```

Answer (score -1):

You are converting to int in the end which will cap all values to the smaller(!) int value. C does not round in this case.

[Edit: Sorry, my previous version of this answer contained a wrong part.]

Comment: > whole calculation being done in integer format.

This is not a problem. int is promoted to float whenever required - this is clearly defined by the language.

Comment: > In C there is a difference between 1 * 0.1 and 1.0 * 0.1.

What difference? Both of this results in float, as integer is promoted to float by operator *.